# Crontab running help

Tags: cron

I'm trying to run a bash script every day to check if a certificate is expired or not. I have never been able to get it to work properly, and I think it might be a problem with the cron I have set up.

If I go to run the job manually using "sh renew_lets_encrypt_cert.sh", it works just fine and the cert updates.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 0 * * * sh /home/username/renew_lets_encrypt_cert.sh > /home/username/renew_errors.log 2>&1
#
```

One thing I noticed just now is that I forgot to put the "#" at the bottom of the file, was that necessary? The file path is correct, as well as the file path for the error log (which contains nothing).

Other than that, I don't know what could be causing the problem...Any help would be appreciated.